# Is there an algorithm to find shortest path (hop count) between only the connected dominating nodes?

Tags: graph-algorithm, shortest-path

Given a connected dominating nodes D in an undirected graph G; I search for an algorithm that can find the shortest paths (hop count) only between those dominating nodes.
Thank you.

Comment: What are "connected dominating nodes"?

Comment: Let D be a subset of V (D ⊆ V); D is a dominating set (DS) if and only if every node v∈ V is either in D or has at least one neighbor node u ∈ D. DS becomes a connected dominating set (CDS), If all the nodes in D is connected.

Comment: ok.. so why would the shortest path algorithm over D be any different than over any other graph?